# How to Insert Arabic data into mysql database from android

Tags: android, mysql, database, internationalization, arabic

It has Android application adds data to the database,
But when you enter data in the Arab,
Show "?????"  .
I tried all the ways.

File config.inc.php :

```
<?php 

$username = "*****"; 
$password = "****"; 
$host = "*****"; 
$dbname = "*****"; 

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try 
{ 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 
?>
```

Addition file :

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

$query = "INSERT INTO news (  news_date, news_title, news_body ) VALUES ( :news_date, :news_title, :news_body ) ";
$query_params = array(
    ':news_date'  => $_POST['news_date'],
    ':news_title' => $_POST['news_title'],
    ':news_body'  => $_POST['news_body']
);



try 
{
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

}
catch (PDOException $ex) 
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add News!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "News Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

In the Android project :
Java file :

```
public class addnews extends Dialog {

private Activity mActivity;

private EditText mNewsTitleET;
private EditText mNewsET;

private Button mPublishBtn;
public String username;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private String ADD_URL =
        "http://yazanyazan3.esy.es/newssite/addnews.php";

public addnews(Activity mActivity)
{
    super(mActivity);
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnews);

    mNewsTitleET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title_news);
    mNewsET      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.news_box);
    mPublishBtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.publish_btn);

    Bundle use =getIntent().getExtras();
    username = use.getString("name");

    mPublishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            attempAdding();
        }
    });
}

private void attempAdding()
{
    if (!mNewsTitleET.getText().toString().equals("") &&
            !mNewsET.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        new AddNewsTask().execute();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                "All fields are requires", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public Intent getIntent() {
    return mActivity.getIntent();
}


private class AddNewsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private JSONObject jsonObjectResult = null;

    private String error;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(addnews.this.getContext(),
                "Processing...", "Adding new news", false, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();


        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("news_user",username));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("news_date", dateFormat.format(date).toString()));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("news_title", mNewsTitleET.getText().toString()));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("news_body", mNewsET.getText().toString()));


        jsonObjectResult = jsonParser.makehttprequest(ADD_URL+"?user="+username+"", pairs);

        if (jsonObjectResult == null)
        {
            error = "Error in the connection";
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            if (jsonObjectResult.getInt("success") == 1)
            {
                error = jsonObjectResult.getString("message");
                return true;
            }
            else
                error = jsonObjectResult.getString("message");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dismiss();
    }
} }
```

In the database, I choose utf8 .
And tried all the solutions did not work .
Please help.

Comment: Try adding a static text into database in your addition file (do not read it from request) so you can divide the problem into two parts and you can see if the problem is from android client to php server or from php server to database.

Comment: Please, can you edit my code in the file addition
I hope that you help me I've lost hope.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these tips will help :

Try adding a static text into database in your addition file (do not read it from request) so you can divide the problem into two parts and you can see if the problem is from android client to PHP server or from PHP server to database like :

```
<?php

/*
  please type the Arabic string(salam) with your own keyboard and do not 
  copy my version because I used Persian keyboard.
*/
$arabic_string = 'سلام';

file_put_contents("arabic_file", $arabic_string);

$query_params = array(
    ':news_date'  => $_POST['news_date'],
    ':news_title' => $_POST['news_title'],
    ':news_body'  => $arabic_string
);

?>
```

now check both the "arabic_file" content and also the database.

-If the file was not ok(contained gibberish) then the problem is from your php server(like maybe it does not support arabic language,...).

-If the database was not ok(gibberish again) then maybe the problem is your database or the way PHP's PDO is inserting data into the database, and you should specify the encoding for your connection like :

```
$connection_str = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8";
```

-If everything was ok then the problem is the way the Arabic strings are coming from your android device.